# Calculating vertical displacement to intercept the perimeter of the circle after a horizontal shift

Tags: equation-solving, graphics, regions, geometry

I can't come upon a solution for the question below. The background of the actual work is not interesting for the question, so l won't explain why I need the solution. I would be very thankful if someone could help, even though the question may be pretty simple for the Mathematica Stack Exchange.

I have a circle with a radius of `184` cm. I moved a point placed on the top of the circle horizontally `17` cm to the left. Now, I want to move this point vertically downward such that it intercepts the perimeter of the circle. How many centimeters should I move the point downward to intersect the perimeter of the circle again? How can this problem be set up with Mathematica?

[image: sketch of problem]

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Might this be a question for the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) page, rather than the Mathematica page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the circle with radius: r is at the origin. Then the top point has coordinates:

```
r=184;
top= {0,r}
```

The point to the left with a displacement: dis of  has coordinates:

```
dis= -17;
l= {dis,r}
```

The point left down on the circle: ld makes an angle phi with the vertical axis:

```
phi= ArcTan[r,dis]
```

And the point on the circle:

```
ld= r {Sin[phi],Cos[phi]}
```

The distance you are searching is then:

```
dely= r-ld[[2]]

184 - 33856/Sqrt[34145]
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 5):

```
sol = First@
  Solve[{x^2 + y^2 == 184^2, x == -17, y > 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -17, y -> Sqrt[33567]}}

```
x = 184 - y /. sol
```

> 184 - Sqrt[33567]

---

*Geometric solution*

```
d1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 184];
c1 = d1 /. Disk :> Circle;
r1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {-17, 184}];

sol = RegionIntersection[c1, RegionBoundary@r1]
```

> Point[{{0, 184}, {-17, Sqrt[33567]}}]

```
GraphicsRow[{
  Graphics[{d1, Red, r1, Yellow, AbsolutePointSize@Large, 
    Point@RegionCentroid@d1}]
  , Graphics[{c1, FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Thick], r1, 
    AbsolutePointSize@Large, Red, sol}
   , PlotRange -> {{-20, 10}, {180, 186}}]
  }]
```

---

[image]

Comment: That’s an awesome solution, thanks